# Tried and tested way to repair malfunctioning thought process

Tags: cognitive-psychology, depression

Could someone here lead me to tried and tested methods to repair a malfunctioning thought process after depression? I have read through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_disorder. Specifically to correct the ones here - Circumstantiality, Derailment, Echolalia, Flight of ideas, Loss of goal, Perseveration and Pressure of speech.

Answer (score 2):

[Psychotherapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychotherapy) is not something to be practiced without a licensed professional. It is very easy to cause damage to someone using tried and tested psychotherapy techniques. However from the standpoint of theory [Psychodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychodynamics), [Cognitive Behaviour Therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy) and [Interpersonal Therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpersonal_psychotherapy) are typically used to treat depression.

Comment: My doctor is only interested in prescribing pills and not in providing interpersonal therapy

Comment: @Shivanand you have a psychiatrist and most only provide drugs. You also need a psychologist someone who does psychotherapy.